# TYPO3 Database integrity check search for NULL

Tags: typo3

I would like to create queries via the database integrity check extension (search) which show me all files/images without title, alternative and description.

Unfortunately there are also database fields here which are NULL - can I still query this somehow?
Currently the backend query allows only to search for empty strings, not NULL.

A direct SQL query is unfortunately not possible/not desired here because it is about several hundred files and these should be adjusted with the stored query directly via the backend.

Comment: Quick concept: You can fix your DB to set default value for column `''` instead of `NULL` and/or create a scheduler task which will regullary update all `NULL` cells to empty val.

Comment: Hi biesor, thanks for the fast reply!

But to what extent does this affect other queries? I think that had a point to set the fields to ZERO, right?
Would this perhaps also make sense as a feature request?

Comment: We don't know your database structure and what other queries are. You need to examine it yourself.

Comment: Only the TYPO3 standard tables/fields, I have not changed anything, so the question if I change this what effect does this have, there will surely have been a reason to declare these as NULL